# Issue while adding tesseract library.

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ocr, tesseract

I want to implement OCR scanning. I added tesseract library from flowing link.

http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/#

But after adding the file mentioned and changing the settings, I am getting linker error.
 I am working on latest Xcode version.

Error message : clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you making sure to also include Leptonica, and all of the other required libraries that Tesseract depends on?

Comment: @NathanM - I just made changes as per mentioned in the link. Is this necessary to include Leptonica?

Comment: I don't really think so... but just make sure it's present, unless it's already statically linked into Tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

Only keep tesseract-ios/classes/Tesseract.h and tesseract-ios/classes/Tesseract.mm and remove all other files in tesseract-ios folder in your project bundle. Then build again. Hope it will successful. If it doesn't work please let me know.